# Swift - How to animate image view?

Tags: swift

Im trying to make an image view to animate and move in a random direction on the screen, but after building and running it in the simulator its just staying still.

I tried to use this piece of code.

```
    @objc func updatePosition() {
    let maxX = view.frame.maxX - imageViewWidth
    let maxY = view.frame.maxY - imageViewHeight
    let xCoord = CGFloat.random(in: 0...maxX)
    let yCoord = CGFloat.random(in: 0...maxY)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xCoord, y: yCoord)
        }
    
    }
```

This is what I got.

```
    import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var Stuck: UIImageView!
    
       
    @objc func updatePosition() {
        let maxX = view.frame.maxX - 128
        let maxY = view.frame.maxY - 103
        let xCoord = CGFloat.random(in: 0...maxX)
        let yCoord = CGFloat.random(in: 0...maxY)
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.Stuck.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: xCoord, y: yCoord)
        }
    }
```

Ive tried to implement the example above and various others, I think my problem is that I don't know how to manipulate @iboutlets, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Make sure there are no constraints holding the image view in place.

Comment: You have declared the updatePosition method but I don't see any code where you call it. So it never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code there is nothing wrong, so I decided to try it myself.
Everything works fine as expected, I gave these constraints to the image view `x: 0, y: 0, h: 128, w: 103`.
The problem could be that your function isn't called, make sure of that.
[image: It works]